# Create blank file inside directory with Uri

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

I am trying to create a file inside a directory using Uri.
For the new file to be created, I do not have the Uri, but I do have for the directory inside which I want to create the file.
I am following this guide: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#grant-access-directory

So now I have persistent access to (say) `[Internal storage]/MyFilesCollection`
I also have the Uri to access it.
I want to create a file inside this directory, basically (say) `[Internal storage]/MyFilesCollection/myFile.txt`

I do not want to use `Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` as it opens the system picker for every file I want to create. Also I have persistent write access to the folder. So is there any way to create the file without using intents?

Edit:
Code used to gain persistent access:

```
val contentResolver = applicationContext.contentResolver
val takeFlags: Int = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or
        Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(uri, takeFlags)
```

Thanks.

Comment: "now I have persistent access to (say) [Internal storage]/MyFilesCollection" -- what do you mean by this? What code did you use to get it? "I have persistent write access to the folder" -- what do you mean by this? What code did you use to get it?

Comment: @CommonsWare added the code for persistent access.

Comment: If you obtained the folder and access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE then after that you can create as many files and subfolders in it as you want without using an intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to guess that you are using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` to get the `Uri` in the first place. If so:

Step #1: Use `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri()` to get a `DocumentFile` associated with the `Uri` that you got from `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`

Step #2: [Call `createFile()` on that `DocumentFile`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/documentfile/provider/DocumentFile?hl=en#createFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) to get a `DocumentFile` representing the document that you wish to place in this tree

Step #3: Call `getUri()` on that new `DocumentFile` to get a `Uri` representing the document

Step #4: Call `openOutputStream()` on a `ContentResolver`, passing in that `Uri`, to get an `OutputStream`, which you can use to write to the document

Comment: I think it would be `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri()` not DocumentTree

Comment: Can you showan example please i dont have android studio and just use java straight?